# Sitecore powershell, Excel export does not contain all the records after decoding the rich text field

Tags: powershell-extensions

I wrote a script to capture all content from specific location of the content tree, as part of this script I need to take out only the text from the rich text fields. I use the HtmlAgilityPack to filter out the text out from HTML. I had about 3000 records before decoding now I only get around 1200 records. I can see all the records in result view but when export it excel format I only see limited content. other formats(csv.json) contain all the results

```
Function SanitiseHtml($html){
   $doc = New-Object HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
   $doc.LoadHtml($html)
   $sanitise = $doc.DocumentNode.InnerText -replace 'amp;',' '
   $sanitise = $sanitise -replace '&nbsp;', ' '
   $sanitise = $sanitise -replace '&rsquo;',' '
   $decoded = ([System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlDecode($sanitise))
   return $decoded
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a problem with how Excel shows the values. Can you see all the records if you open the CSV file with text editor?

Comment: Yes, I can see all in the CSV

Comment: If you export to XLSX, then open the document in Excel do you see all the content in the box above the grid when you select the cell? Another test would be to open the xlsx in Excel and save as CSV to verify again that all the data is there.

Comment: I can see all the data as expected on the List View window. But lower number of rows (less than half) when I export it to Excel. The file size is much smaller than the size of the csv file. However, I do get all the records on XSL if I get rid of the decoding bit which is strange. Also, I couldn’t replicate this issue for smaller number of records. I really need the decoding bit ☹

Comment: I had a similar kind of issue while dealing with accents but it was for Single line text. I run the script and I'll get all the data in the required format in List view but not when I tried downloading using CSV format. So I always download it in Excel format, open in Excel and save it as CSV UTF-8 format. Kindly try the same.